# How to display hovercard for respective links?

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my HTML outline:

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="votes">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/upvote.png" class="sm-icon color-on-hover"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/downvote.png" class="sm-icon color-on-hover"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fav.jpg" class="sm-icon color-on-hover"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-text">
    Comment goes here..
    <p class="author"><a href="#">Author name</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu hovercard">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    Hovercard content
  </div>
</div>
```

This is just one comment's structure, there are multiple comments dynamically generated. So I cannot assign that much ID's.
part from this other posts also have author names which will need hovercard. I am using somewhat similar structure for them too..

So, is there a way I can do that using the class name?

I am using jQuery:

```
$(".author").hover(function(){
        $(".hovercard").fadeIn(100);
    });
```

This displays all the hovercards together.

Drop a comment if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) for this:

```
$(".author").hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('.comment-text').next(".hovercard").fadeIn(100);
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2u2d0rpp/2/)